# Can I change something in my C# script to avoid using interactive user in DCOM settings?

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, ssis

I have an ssis package that copies a template to a folder and names it accordingly using a file system task. Then in my data flow task, I pull data from a query and write to the excel file just created. This works just fine with the "launching user" Excel Application DCOM setting. Then I have a script task reformat the data types in the raw excel file. However, the job fails at my script task unless I set the DCOM configuration to use "interactive user". Problem with this is, even when my user account is logged in, it won't work unless I actively rdp into the server and have the window open on my computer. Is there a workaround I can include in my code or elsewhere to avoid having to use the interactive user setting? Here is my script:

```
public void Main()
        {
            string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
            try
            {
                string FileName = Dts.Variables["User::FullDestinationFile"].Value.ToString();

                //Init

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                xlApp.Visible = false;

                //Set active worksheet

                Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName);
                Sheets xlSheets = xlWorkbook.Worksheets;
                Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)xlApp.Worksheets[1];
                sheet.Select(Type.Missing);

                //Set formatting on columns

                Range pDate = sheet.Range[sheet.Cells[5, 1], sheet.Cells[sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1]];
                pDate.NumberFormat = "General";
                pDate.HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;


                //Save and Close
                xlWorkbook.Save();
                xlWorkbook.Close(true);

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }

            catch (Exception exception)
            {

                // Create Log File for Errors
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Dts.Variables["User::FullDestinationFile"].Value.ToString() + datetime + ".log"))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;

                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: I've seen your questions and as you're experiencing, using the interop Excel bits with SSIS is painful. Two approaches I could see to make this less so. 1) Rework the Excel extract portion to be an SSRS report, assuming it's installed in your ecosystem, that exports gracefully to Excel. No more need for Office and paying for a license on the SQL Server box along with the increased downtime due to patching. The SSIS portion then becomes a problem of saving the export with a good file name - much easier to manage and plenty of examples out there

Comment: The other approach might be to look at using something like the [EPPlus library](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus). Yes, it'll be a lot of rework in the beginning but it should avoid the interactivity challenges you're running into as last I recall, it's literally just writing the XML that is Excel. The interop libraries are spinning up an instance of Excel to do all the voodoo, that they do, so well, or mediocre